Uno Platform GTK/SKIA and Persian/Arabic Language
I just stared to learn how to use uno platform to make desktop apps for ubuntu. I'm running vscode on ubuntu 22.04 and uno extension and other extensions as needed. the problem is when I use persian or arabic language, they split into characters and letters and get mixed and unreadable like the image below:

I don't know what to do. I updated all the ubuntu packages and get language packages but nothing helps.
